# Getting extra characters while loading data

Tags: python, pandas, sas

While loading data using `read_sas` from sas dataset in Python getting `b'` along with every string. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `endcoding=utf-8`

#### Code:

```
import pandas as pd
mydf=pd.read_sas("\home\mypath\mydataset.sas7bdat",format = 'sas7bdat', encoding="utf-8")
```

If the sas dataset is small, I would recommend loading from CSV file instead of sas dataset. Performance loading from SAS using Python is poor.